# How to make recursive associations with Feathers.JS?

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I'm trying to make recursive associations with Feathers.JS but keep running into issues that make it seem like it's not possible. I want users to be associated with other users via a foreign key called parentID. The problem is that I can't reference the user schema before it's defined, so I can't add a parent to the user schema.  I've tried making the user schema with `Type.Recursive`, but schemas can only be `Type.Object` or `Type.Intersect`.  Can anyone describe how to do this with a brand new Typescript/MySQL FeathersJS project? This seems very basic, but I've spent an unreasonable amount of time trying to get this to work. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

I guess a better example would be to start with the [feathers-chat](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat) example and add replies to messages from there.

One would expect to be able to change the `messageSchema` const at *feathers-chat-ts/src/services/messages/messages.schema.ts:9* to `Type.Recursive` with its parameter being an arrow function that returns the original `Type.Object` call with an added line inside this object that looks like `parent: Type.Optional(Type.Ref(_messageSchema))`, add an optional `parentId` to the schema and that would be the end of it, but when `messageSchema` is a `Type.Recursive` instead of a `Type.Object` it causes several TypeScript errors and fails to compile.  Is this a bug in FeathersJS or am I missing something?